What caused Xubuntu's screen brightness settings to change between 22.04 and 24.04?
In Xubuntu 22.04's Power Manager's panel icon's GUI, I could reduce my screen's brightness until it was entirely black. In Xubuntu 24.04, the lowest setting in the GUI is much higher than "entirely black". I have read through the change log for Xfce 4.18 and 4.16, but I cannot find any reference to this. What software changed in order to change this behaviour between Xubuntu 22.04 and 24.04?

I'm not aware of any change; but have you explored the jammy (22.04) & noble (24.04) manifest or seed files looking for differences?  (the manifest files show what is included on an ISO & are available for Ubuntu ISOs when downloaded, the seed file(s) control what goes on the ISO during build)
